# How to change Jenkins mirror, when proxy forbids keyword ftp

Tags: url, jenkins, proxy, ftp, mirror

When I install a jenkins-plugin like the 'git-plugin', then jenkins redirects my requests to the mirror *ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de*. But I work behind a corporate proxy that forbid requests to URL containing the word 'ftp'.

Is there a way to choose or disable the mirror when downloading plugins for jenkins? Jenkins has no problems installing plugins from sites that do not contain 'ftp'.

Here is the error from jenkins log-view:

```
Dez 22, 2016 3:46:54 PM INFORMATION hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob run
Starting the installation of Git client plugin on behalf of admin-ci
Dez 22, 2016 3:46:54 PM SCHWERWIEGEND hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob run
Failed to install Git client plugin
hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to download from http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/git-client/2.1.0/git-client.hpi (redirected to: http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/jenkins/plugins/git-client/2.1.0/git-client.hpi)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1169)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1666)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1864)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1640)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/jenkins/plugins/git-client/2.1.0/git-client.hpi
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1926)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1921)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1920)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1490)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1121)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/jenkins/plugins/git-client/2.1.0/git-client.hpi
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1876)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:2982)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getHeaderFieldLong(URLConnection.java:629)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLengthLong(URLConnection.java:501)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLength(URLConnection.java:485)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1120)
    ... 7 more

    enter code here
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Jenkins is using http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json as a "load balancer" url which forwards you to the closest geographical mirror json (i.e. http://ftp-nyc.osuosl.org/pub/jenkins/updates/current/update-center.json for me). What you can do is use your own json file for that purpose by installing this plugin and host json file anywhere you want (i.e. internally):

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/UpdateSites+Manager+plugin

[image]

Comment: I feel I'm almost there, but not quite: I downloaded the official update-center.json and changed all `updates.jenkins-ci.org/downloads`  occurrences to `archives.jenkins-ci.org` so the package urls match what my proxy allows, then changed my updatecenter url to a personal webserver containing this JSON file. I see Jenkins' GET on my server log, but the plugin download still tries `updates.jenkins` and gets redirected. =(

Comment: hmm, I think my problem is with Jenkins not correctly updating the json files inside its *updates* directory. I got it working by replacing the URLs in default.json. I'll try to reproduce using a fresh install an open a bug report. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction! =)

Answer (score 5):

I found a workaround:

1. Download the plugin direct from http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/gitlab-plugin/latest/
2. Upload the hpi-file into jenkins. There is an
   upload field in http://host:8080/pluginManager/advanced.

**But this is only a workaround.** I would like to get an answer to my question: "*Is there a way to choose or disable the mirror when downloading plugins for jenkins?*"

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the real solution here is to tell your firewall manager to block ftp rather than blocking urls with ftp in them - that's a terrible rule.